# Java Restful Web Service using Jersey implementation developed in Eclipse IDE not deployed and call on JBoss server

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jboss7.x, jersey-2.0

I have created a web service that uses Jersey implementation. It is working fine when using it locally in system. But, it creates problem when i deploy it on JBoss AS 7 server. Somehow i resolved that problem by adding following code in web.xml file :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name> resteasy.scan </param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name> resteasy.scan.providers </param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>serviceClass</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This one solves my problem for deployment of service on JBoss server. But when i hit my service method, the following error occur :

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet s1 threw exception
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:94)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My service class is as follow :

```
@Path("/service")
public class Service {

    @GET
    @Path("/getfontlist")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML   })
    public FontList  getFontList()
    {
        FontList fontList = callMethod.getFontList();
        return fontList;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getcolorlist")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ColorList getColorList()
    {
        ColorList colorList =  callMethod.getColorList();
        return colorList;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getproducts")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Categories getProducts()
    {
        Categories productCategoriesList =  callMethod.getProducts();
        return productCategoriesList;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getcliparts")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Categories getCliparts()
    {
        Categories clipartCategoriesList = callMethod.getCliparts();
        return clipartCategoriesList;
    }
}
```

I am facing problem when i hits service method with path : domain/project_name/service_name/method_name

Is anyone have faced this problem ? If yes, then kindly reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your package name of  called 'serviceClass' ? This seems not like a normal package name

Comment: yes. Package name is serviceClass. Should i have to change the package name

Comment: Whenever I see `NoSuchMethodError`, the first thing that comes to mind is dependency version issue (and it is usually the cause).

Comment: i am using jersey 2.0

Comment: Did you replace RESTEasy with Jersey or are you just including all the Jersey libraries in your deployment?

Comment: I am using Jersey only and deploy jersey jar files with project.

Comment: To neglect RestEasy, i have allready add code in web.xml file. You can see that in above mentioned code

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins How can i replace RESTEasy with Jersey in my service ?

Comment: If you're just using standard JAX-RS annotations and/or configuration then you shouldn't need to do anything. Just remove the Jersey stuff from your `web.xml` and ignoring RESTEasy.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue and this is what made it work. I had to go through a lot of posts here in which it kept emphasizing the entries need to be set right in web.xml and for my case this is where the problem seemed to occur.

This was a piece of my service class:

```
package com.tel.rest.customer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.json.JSONException;

import com.sun.jersey.api.JResponse;

@Path("/PR/customers")
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer{...}
```

The web.xml was something like this:

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.eteller.rest.customer</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

This was the error i was seeing:

```
13:29:07,921 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eTellerRest].[Jersey REST Service]] (http--172.25.8.233-8080-3) Allocate exception for servlet Jersey REST Service: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_85]
```

To fix this I had to remove these line of codes from the web.xml to make sure that JBoss can do what it needs to do:

```
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.eteller.rest.customer</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Once i removed this from my web.xml I was able to deploy and use the services on my JBoss server.

Not sure if this helps but you could try it.

Regards
Ali.

Comment: ali, could you please tell what jar file you have added for jersey implementation. It will be a great  help for me.

Comment: @Shaun here is the list:

jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
java-json.jar
jboss-vfs-3.2.9.Final-redhat-1.jar
jersey-client-1.19.jar
jersey-core-1.19.jar
jersey-json-1.19.jar
jersey-server-1.19.jar
jersey-servlet-1.19.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

Hope this helps.